# php code not working the way I want it for Search function

Tags: php, search, foreach

Searching one word works perfectly. I would like to have two or more words work as well.

So far I got this far, with the results being this if I search multiple words:

```
SELECT id, title, tag, type 
FROM table WHERE **AND** p.id LIKE '%flower%' OR title LIKE '%flower%' OR tag LIKE '%flower%' OR type LIKE '%flower%' 
AND p.id LIKE '%floral%' OR title LIKE '%floral%' OR tag LIKE '%floral%' OR type LIKE '%floral%' 
ORDER BY title
```

How do I make use of the **AND** properly so that when there is more than one word search I don't get the extra AND in my code.

Is there a more efficient way?

```
if (count($error) < 1) {
  $searchSQL = "SELECT id, title, tag, type     
                FROM table
                WHERE ";

 $searcheach = explode(" ", $searchTerms);

foreach($searcheach as $searchword) {

//if more than one word do this else do that
 if(strpos(trim($searchTerms), ' ') !== false) {
     $searchSQL .= "AND p.id LIKE '%{$searchword}%' 
                OR title LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
                OR tag LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
                OR type LIKE '%{$searchword}%' ";
     } 
     else {
         $searchSQL .= "p.id LIKE '%{$searchword}%' 
                OR title LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
                OR tag LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
                OR type LIKE '%{$searchword}%' ";
         }  

}
$searchSQL .= "ORDER BY title";
```

Comment: Im sorry but your question is very unclear... Could you elaborate on exactly what you're trying to do ? What is the purpose of the `AND` on the first part of the if statement?

Comment: Have you tried [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html)? It'll make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$words = explode(' ', $searchTerms);

$clauses = array()
foreach($words as $word) {
    $safeword = mysql_real_escape_string($word);
    $clauses[] = "(p.id LIKE '%{$safeword}%' OR title LIKE '%{$safeword} OR etc... )";
}
$clause = implode(' AND ', $clauses);

$sql = "SELECT ... WHERE $clause ORDER BY title";
```

Comment: Aside from using BOOLEAN FULL TEXT searches, this is the option I would go with, personally...

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do

```
$searchSQL = "SELECT id, title, tag, type     
            FROM table
            WHERE (1=1)";
```

Now you can always prepend `AND` before each condition

Also, it looks like you missed parenthesis, I believe it should be

```
$searchSQL .= "AND (p.id LIKE '%{$searchword}%' 
            OR title LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
            OR tag LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
            OR type LIKE '%{$searchword}%') "
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the 1=1 filter so that when searching for multiple words, the sql will be:

```
SELECT id, title, tag, type 
  FROM table 
  WHERE 1=1 
    AND p.id LIKE '%flower%' 
    OR title LIKE '%flower%' 
    OR tag LIKE '%flower%' 
    OR type LIKE '%flower%' 
    AND p.id LIKE '%floral%' 
    OR title LIKE '%floral%' 
    OR tag LIKE '%floral%' 
    OR type LIKE '%floral%' 
  ORDER BY title
```

And the code to do that would be:

```
if (count($error) < 1) {
  $searchSQL = "SELECT id, title, tag, type     
                FROM table
                WHERE 1=1";

 $searcheach = explode(" ", $searchTerms);

foreach($searcheach as $searchword) {

//if more than one word do this else do that
 if(strpos(trim($searchTerms), ' ') !== false) {
     $searchSQL .= " AND p.id LIKE '%{$searchword}%' 
                OR title LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
                OR tag LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
                OR type LIKE '%{$searchword}%' ";
     } 
     else {
         $searchSQL .= "p.id LIKE '%{$searchword}%' 
                OR title LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
                OR tag LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
                OR type LIKE '%{$searchword}%' ";
         }  

}
$searchSQL .= "ORDER BY title";
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to build up all my terms as an array and then use implode:

```
foreach($searcheach as $searchword) {
    $sqlSearchTerms[] = "p.id LIKE '%{$searchword}%' 
     OR title LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
     OR tag LIKE '%{$searchword}%'
     OR type LIKE '%{$searchword}%' ";
}

$searchSQL .= implode(' AND ', $sqlSearchTerms);
```